# Consume a json object , which is basically a list of objects of a class defined in my WCF , in an HTML Win 8 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

so I have a WCF service that returns a list of objects of a class , that has been defined in my WCF's contract and I am supposed to receive the Json object in a Javascript Win 8 app. Now when  I do

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: url_final }).then(function (r) {
            var result = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
document.getElementById("greetingOutput").innerText = result;
}
```

I can see [object Object] in that div ,
any idea how do i see individual elements over there ?

My class is :

```
public class GraphData
    {
        String concerneddate = String.Empty;
        Int32 houroftheday = 0;
        Int32 countathour = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
 var result = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
```

makes `result` a javascript object. now u can get individual properties of that object like that:

```
result.concerneddate;
result.houroftheday; 
result.countathour;
```

I suggest you log the actual result and see the structure of the object.

**UPDATE:**

after seeing your comment, the way to access the properties would be:

```
var resultsArray = result.GetGraphDetailsResult;

for (var i in resultsArray){
var ConcernedDate = resultsArray[i].ConcernedDate;
var CountAtHour = resultsArray[i].CountAtHour;
...
}
```

Comment: I have seen the actual result in a wordpad file , its basically a list of objects like , an array of objects :
{"GetGraphDetailsResult":[{"ConcernedDate":"2012-12-13","CountAtHour":8,"HourOfTheDay":1},{"ConcernedDate":"2012-12-13","CountAtHour":5,"HourOfTheDay":2},{"ConcernedDate":"2012-12-13","CountAtHour":4,"HourOfTheDay":3}]